# No neighbourhood deformation retracts to a point

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am trying to find a pair $(Y,y_0)$ so that no neighbourhood $U\subseteq Y$ of $y_0$ deformation retracts to $y_0$, but I can't find an example of it. I was thinking of some simple space with the discrete topology, maybe? Any suggestions are helpful. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Are you familiar with the [Hawaiian earring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawaiian_earring)?

You might also consider a nice, friendly 2-manifold and then delete a sequence of points with $y_0$ as a limit point.  This puts obstructions to deformation retraction arbitrarily close to $y_0$.

Comment: the hawaiian earring is a nice example! thank you!

Comment: I wrote the following: if we could deformation retract the Hawaiian earring to the point, then its fundamental group would be trivial. However, each loop is homeomorphic to the circle, which has fundamental group $\mathbb{Z}$, and so H itself cannot have trivial fundamental group.

Comment: is this correct?

Comment: @dlc That's right. Rigorously, the earring retracts to any of it's petals. So there is an embedded copy of $\Bbb Z$ inside the $\pi_1$ of Hawaiian earring - that means it's not simply connected.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the space $X = \{0,1,1/2,1/3,\cdots\} \times [0, 1] \cup [0, 1]\times \{0\}$ consisting of a base $[0, 1]$ with sticks of unit lengths glued to each point $1/n$, including it's limit point.

Take any point $x$ on the interior of the limiting stick, that is, on $\{0\} \times (0, 1) \subset X$. Any neighborhood $U$ of $x$ is very not path connected. So $U$ can never be even homotopy equivalent to $x$, let alone be deformation retracted to $x$.

Note that both my example and the example in the other answer exploits local disasters. In this case my space at $x$ is not locally connected, whereas for Eric Tower's example the space is not locally simply connected.